# remove facebook like button social text

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to remove the social text from the **facebook like button** in order to fit into the width I have spare left but I can't find how on the facebook developers site

So what I want to remove is "Be the first of your friends to like this." text

As seen here:

[image]

Comment: What is `with` all of the `code blocks`? That is an image, could you give us the code?

Comment: @VinylScratch i added the code blocks in order to process the post cause it needed more info... as for the solution the answer below solves the problem

Comment: @VinylScratch waiting time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Then change the layout to button_count and uncheck send button