# How to remove facebook like button social text?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to remove the social text from the facebook like button in order to fit into the width, you can see Image 1.

I have read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384586/remove-facebook-like-button-social-text).

But when I access https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ , I can  change the *"layout to button_count"*, but I can't find  *"uncheck send button"*. How can I do?

BTW, In the official website, it can display a Like Button without text, you can see Image 2.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: _'but I can't find "uncheck send button".'_ - what send button? Neither of your screenshots appears to show one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384586/remove-facebook-like-button-social-text told me that `Then change the layout to button_count and uncheck send button`

Comment: That response is almost _eleven_ years old, so it probably doesn't reflect the current state of the plugin any more.

Comment: Image 2 is a screenshot from Facebook. Facebook can of course do what every they want. They might not even use the SDK that you are trying to use.

Comment: @HelloCW can you share a link that you like button is really showing? for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Have yo tried the suggested code instead of the FB button generator ?
Here you go :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" 
        src="https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1
             &version=v16.0
             &appId=YOURAPPID
             &autoLogAppEvents=1" 
        nonce="FOKrbAYI">
  </script>

  <!-- Your like button code -->
  <div class="fb-like" 
       data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
       data-width=""
       data-layout="button_count" 
       data-action="like" 
       data-size="small"  
       data-share="false">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I get the same result when I use  suggested code.

Comment: did you replace YOURAPPID by your app id ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested and this only shows like button:

```html
<div class="fb-like"
  data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"
  data-width="500"
  data-layout="button"
  data-action="like"
  data-size="small"
  data-share="false"></div>
```

As you know you should have this in your head tag and also add your keys to it:

```html
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v16.0" nonce="vnvxh4b9"></script>
```

You can add app ID after `version=v16.0` like this. `123456789` is your app ID:

````
```html
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
   src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v16.0&appId=123456789"
   nonce="vnvxh4b9"></script>
````

````
Also you can use CSS to hide everything else:

```css
.fb-like {
    width: 60px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
````

[See the result in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kq0uopy/)

**Note: If you want to show count on button just change `data-layout="button"` in the div to

```
data-layout="button_count"
```

And respectfully increase the width if you use CSS!

Comment: not possible to hide it because it's inside an iframe, + has no ID but a class that seems dynamic. Untargetable !

Comment: @rafa226 Updated the answer. You were right! thanks for giudance.